# Raise error when rounding of decimal points occurs

Tags: sql-server

I have `[BRKTFRT1] [decimal](7, 4`) column in `@MyTable` table.

When I try to insert the value `34.1234555` it is successfully inserting `34.1235` into the column. Actually, I need to prevent this rounding and raise an error if any such rounding become necessary. How can we add such a constraint?

Note: One idea is to check the length of input string. But I would like to add it as a CHECK constraint so that developers won’t miss this constraint.

Note: I am using SQL Server 2012

Note:I am not trying to "avoid" rounding. I need to inform the calling program that they supplied incorrect value (by raising error).

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (BRKTFRT1 [decimal](7, 4) )

DECLARE @MyStringDecimal VARCHAR(20)
SET @MyStringDecimal = '34.1234555'

INSERT INTO @MyTable (BRKTFRT1) VALUES (@MyStringDecimal)
SELECT BRKTFRT1 FROM @MyTable
```

Comment: `SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ON` Worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188791.aspx)

> When SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT is ON, an error is generated after a loss of precision occurs in an expression. [...]
>   Loss of precision occurs when an attempt is made to store a value with a fixed precision in a column or variable with less precision